# Is there a nice expression for $f(x) = (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, polynomials

While I was solving a problem, I stumbled upon this function 
$$f(x) = (1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)\cdots$$
I tried to write out the first few products but I couldn't recognize any meaningful pattern. Is there some well known facts about this special function?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the generating function
for the number of partitions into
distinct parts:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html